# Getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The requested content does not exist.) after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My create-react-app is throwing the following error when I deploy it to azure. App is working fine without any issue.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (The requested content does not exist.)

I am not getting the error in localhost. I spent lot of time figuring out the issue, but not able to find any solution. Please help me.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpjHj.png)

Thank you